# Call stored procedure DB2 IN Grails

Tags: grails, db2, ibm-midrange

The community I am on a project or it is code with Grails DB2. My problem is that I have a hard time calling database stored procedures in my Grails code.
Can someone help me. thank you in advance

> logerror: 2019-02-15 10:39:30.556 +0000 [http-nio-8081-exec-7] DEBUG
>   g.a.c.s.s.d.ApiController [/datagw][][0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] -
>   {"method":"executeSpRow","data":"{\"success\":false,\"errorMessage\":\"ASTER_GET_BUREAU
>   => com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCSQLSyntaxErrorException: [SQL0104] El\u00e9ment syntaxique ASTER_GET_BUREAU n'est pas correct.
>   El\u00e9ments possibles : ( CL END GET SET CALL DROP FREE HOLD LOCK
>   OPEN.\"}"}

[image: postman test]

Comment: Shouldn't "sqlRequest" be the SQL command rather than just the name of the stored procedure? Then "sqlParams" should be the values to replace parameter markers in "sqlRequest".

Comment: Also, please do not paste screen shots, it is much harder to test or modify code as I have to type it all in rather than cut and paste code. Once the screen shot is replaced by text, I will give you an example of what I am talking about.

Comment: {
  "sqlRequest": "ASTER_GET_BUREAU",
  "connectionId":  {{connexionId}},
  "sqlParams": 
  {
      "call aster_get_bureau":('00001')
  }
}

Comment: Hi, you need to edit the question to include that text, not add it in a comment. Thanks.